# Can a Pokémon evolve while it's fainted?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Let's say I level up a Pokémon until I get the option to evolve it. Will I still be able to evolve that Pokémon if it faints in battle or will it need to be revived first?

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: @xehpuk Depending on how far the OP was, setting this up to test would have been tricky in the early stages of the game.

Comment: @Wondercricket This is correct. I’ve only unlocked the first two areas so far, so I haven’t had many pokemon evolve yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can still evolve Pokémon while they are fainted. I tested this with a Grotle, and it allowed me to evolve into a Torterra.

[image: Grotlle fainted]

[image: Torterra fainted]

Comment: I like how the Pokémon stays fainted after evolving.

Comment: @Stevoisiak you just reminded me of an old feature of Rare Candy: it will revive a fainted Pokemon

Comment: @Robotnik Presumably that's because the base HP has risen enough that it goes up a point? I wonder if it still works if the HP doesn't change on level up?

Comment: @Showsni Is that even possible? I think you always gain HP on level up, I don't think there's any way to avoid that (well, now that I think about it, *maybe* one of the weird glitch pokemon from gen 1 with invalid stats?)

Comment: @Hearth There is Shedinja whose gimmick is to only have 1HP and has a talent which only makes it take damage by super effective moves. I have never taken the chance to try a rare candy on it to see if it comes back to life, and (sadly) doesn't exist in Legends Arceus.